Why PrintOptions.page_height of Selenium is ignored by some websites?
Selenium has print_page method that can return base64 encoded PDF representation of whatever is loaded by Selenium. That method, accepts PrintOptions object which as the name suggests, can set various options for the rendering of the PDF (e.g. page_height/width, margins, ...)
For all the websites that I've tried, the PrintOptions.page_height property works as expected;
from selenium import webdriver
import base64

selenium_driver = webdriver.Firefox()

selenium_driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

print_options = PrintOptions()
print_options.page_height = 10 #set the height of the pdf pages

base64_encoded = selenium_driver.print_page(print_options)

with open("print.pdf", 'wb') as file:
    file.write(base64.b64decode(base64_encoded))


But for some websites (such as this demo of Roundcube), page_height property is completely ignored and pdf is generated by another set of values (A3 sizes in this case). Why is this the case?
URL to test (print friendly version of an email):
https://demo.roundcubeplus.com/?_task=mail&_safe=0&_uid=388&_mbox=INBOX&_action=print&_extwin=1
selenium: v4.25.0
geckodriver: v0.35.0
update:
This issue is different from this bug (stackoverflow link) in the sense that page_height is completely ignored rather than being non-exact.

For anyone having this issue, the culprit is CSS size property that is being set for page under media print in one of loaded CSS files (bootstrap.min.css)
@media print {
  @page {
    size: a3
  }
}


This behavior occurs might be due to some websites implemented their own print styles and settings through CSS (@media print) or other print-oriented HTML meta tags, which can override Selenium's print options.
You may inject your own custom prnit style like below to see if this works:
selenium_driver.execute_script("""
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = '@page { size: auto; margin: 0mm; } @media print { body { height: 100vh; }}';
    document.head.appendChild(style);
""")

Alternatively, you may also leverage third-party API services like pagesnap.co or similar options.
